# QML component is not found, even in same dir

Tags: qt, qml

I'm creating C++ / QML application. In debug version I want to load QML directly from file and in release build I want to load QML from resources. I want to use `QDir::setSearchPaths` for this:

```
    void GuiController::initQmlPath()
    {
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
        QDir dir( QApplication::applicationDirPath() );
        const bool success = dir.cd( "../../Game/Qml" ); // Depends on project structure
        Q_ASSERT( success );
        QDir::setSearchPaths( "qml", QStringList( dir.absolutePath() ) );
#else
        QDir::setSearchPaths( "qml", QStringList( ":/Game/Qml" ) );
#endif
    }
```

I'm loading components in next way:

```
connect( component, &QQmlComponent::statusChanged, stateSlot );
//component->loadUrl( QUrl( "qml:/MainWindow.qml" ) ); // Not working
component->loadUrl( QUrl::fromLocalFile( "C:/Projects/Launcher/Game/Qml/MainWindow.qml" ) ); // OK
```

When I use a full path in `loadUrl` - everything is OK, but when I use `qml:/MainWindow.qml` - file is found, but it can't load components, that are placed in same folder (simplified):

**MainWindow.qml**

```
Window {
  id: root
  visible: true
  CustomComponent {
  }
}
```

**CustomComponent.qml**

```
Rectangle {
  id: root
  color: "red"
}
```

How to resolve it? (How to set lookup folders in qml engine via searchPath)

Comment: Check whether the `QUrl( "qml:/MainWindow.qml" )` produces a valid url. I am not sure `QUrl` supports search paths.

Comment: Strange that file is found, because it shows correct error ("qml:/MainWindow.qml:28 CustomComponent is not a type")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by making url in next way:

```
QUrl::fromLocalFile( QFileInfo( "qml:/MainWindow.qml" ).absoluteFilePath() );
```

Comment: If you answered your own question, please mark answer as accepted to indicate that it resolves your issue.

Comment: Sure. It was not possible before.